# Modelling and texturing specific wood flooring

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I was wondering how you'd go about modelling and texturing the wooden floor that can be seen in the painting below.

[image: Schachpartie by Hummel]

Of course the "module" is a square and the four wooden planks around it, but doing that and then applying an array to it would not give the same pattern (there would be twice the number of wooden planks around the squares).

Also when I tried to do it it looked really flat and "same-y", and wanted to know how to texture it so it looks more real and making the veins more "bumpy" and having the creases around the planks. WIP below so you can see what I mean.

[image: WIP]

Should I texture each plank one by one? How do I make it more varied/bumpy/veiny/dirty/creasy as in the original painting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The small bumps can be done using a normal map which essentially are images that tell Blender that the surface is not smooth, and to extrude the mesh in and out on the flat planes according to the normal map. There is a pretty good tutorial on how to generate normal maps from texture images [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9eCHC8orIc).

To apply the normal map to your object, head over to the shading workspace.

Add a new image texture node and open the normal map image. At the bottom of the image texture, make sure you select "Non-Color" under the Color Space drop-down menu.

Connect the color output into a Normal Map node, and that into the Normal input for the principled BDSF node.
[image: Node setup for node map]

If you want to go even further with realism, consider checking out this [tutorial by Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzXNZkEoTAk). It's using an older version of Blender, but the same principles still apply. The only main difference would be in setting up the nodes for the reflection maps and all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would a displacement map be overkill in this scenario to actually show the irregularities in the planks? In the original image you can see the creases between the "squares" and the planks, and in some places actual holes in the wood.

Comment: I would probably manually edit the individual planks to add some of those unique features. As far as the creases between the planks/squares, add a bevel modifier with a very fine width to bring out the spaces.
Oh, and look around for various different wood textures. Find some that resemble the same species of wood so that it doesn't look too repetitive.

Comment: As far as displacement maps go, I don't really think they're necessary, but feel free to experiment with them as much as you'd like. See how much of a difference it makes both in quality and render time and decide for yourself. Trial and error really is one of the best ways to learn.